# No redraw after assigning new vertex position with python

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, vertices

I'm trying to write a new operator which modifies my geometry in some way, but I'm struggling with vertex manipulation. I can get the selected vertices fine and also print the individual components. So, lets say I have a vertex `v`. I can get the position of this vertex via `v.co`. But when I set a new value for this vertex with my operator it does not redraw in the 3D View. I assign a new value like this:

```
v.co = Vector((1,2,3))
```

Like said above the 3D View does not update. I have to quit my operator and navigate in the 3D View to update. What do I have to do to make blender update the 3D View correctly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your running the script with the object in edit mode then you can use

```
# Note that bmesh is the module named bmesh, not an instance of a BMesh.
# me is an instance of Mesh, again, not an instance of a BMesh.
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

If your running in object mode then you need something that will trigger an update, not sure if this is the best way but

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects.active
```

triggers an update in the 3dview.

Answer (score 4):

If you use a wrapped bmesh...

```
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
```

... use `update_edit_mesh()` to flush changes. Note that Blender will crash otherwise if geometry was added or removed.

If it's not a wrapped bmesh...

```
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
```

... write the bmesh back to mesh:

```
bm.to_mesh(me)
```

To update a mesh, use:

```
me.update()
```